# How to get field with char data type from new records of SQLite database, and its also generated by triggers using dapper + c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

I see this video :
https://youtu.be/eKkh5Xm0OlU?t=1590

> I'am using SQLite version 3.11.2, and NuGet: Dapper version 1.50.2

I'am trying to get identity auto generated id by triggers from last insert

```
  public static void Save(Model1 model1, List<Model2> model2){

      using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString())){

        var dp = new DynamicParameters(model1);
        dp.Add("@GuidAuto", "", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output);

        cnn.Open();
        using (var trans = cnn.BeginTransaction()){
          try{
              int recordsStat = cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO some_table (a, b) VALUES (@a, @b); SELECT @GuidAuto= @@IDENTITY", dp, trans);
              string rmed = dp.Get<string>("@GuidAuto");
              foreach (var item in model2){
                  item.GuidAuto= rmed;
              }
              try{
                  eff = cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO some_table2(c, GuidAuto) VALUES (@c, @GuidAuto)", model2, transaction: trans);
                  trans.Commit();
              }catch (Exception ex){
                  eff = 0;
                  Console.WriteLine($"Error : { ex.Message }");
                  trans.Rollback();
              }
          }catch(Exception err){
            Console.WriteLine($"Error : { err.Message }");
          } 
        }
      }

  }
```

I got error at this line :

> int recordsStat = cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO some_table (a, b) VALUES (@a, @b); SELECT @GuidAuto= @@IDENTITY", dp, trans);

The output of StackTrace :

```
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter.set_Direction(ParameterDirection value)
at Dapper.DynamicParameters.AddParameters(IDbCommand command, Identity identity)
at Dapper.CommandDefinition.SetupCommand(IDbConnection cnn, Action`2 paramReader)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
at Library.SqliteDataAccess.SavePembedahan(Model1 model1, List`1 model2) in D:\abc\sys\Library\SqliteDataAccess.cs:line 200
at SYS.FormDD.cdr_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\abc\FormDD.cs:line 400
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
```

Sorry for bad english. thank you all, have a nice day.

Comment: 1) I'm reasonably certain that output parameters are not supported in SQLite. 2) `@@IDENTITY` is a SQL Server function and that video uses SQL Server objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite.NET output parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179125/sqlite-net-output-parameter)

Comment: @madreflection Ok, firstly my own GuidAuto (String, by triggers) is PK field, if i select last_insert_rowid()  the result will be GuidAuto right ?

Comment: That's what the individual who answered the duplicate I suggested seemed to be saying. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @madreflection still got "Specified method is not supported."

Comment: @madreflection i changed  
cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO some_table (a, b) VALUES (@a, @b); SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS @RekamMedis", dp, trans)

Comment: Did you remove the line that adds the output parameter? That's what's causing the original exception.

Comment: @madreflection i tried to edit like this, dp.Add("@RekamMedis", "", DbType.String); and at the Execute function, "INSERT INTO some_table (a, b) VALUES (@a, @b); SELECT last_insert_rowid()", Than the line of > string rmed = dp.Get<string>("@RekamMedis"); does not have value from GuidAuto (String, by triggers) is PK field

Comment: `dp.Get` retrieves a value from an output parameter. You're now adding it as an input parameter. You can't expect it to be populated because it's not the right parameter direction and the right parameter direction for that expectation is not supported. Your entire technique is based on a video for a totally different RDBMS where it is viable. Your learning material does not apply to SQLite so it's not helpful to you.

Comment: @madreflection I see, i appreciate it. did you have a solution about that ? just want it return my own GuidAuto (String, by triggers) is PK field, and use it for next Execution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont know why, but for my case it's work. thank you

```
string uid = con.Query<string>("SELECT uid from sometable WHERE ROWID = (SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM sometable)", new DynamicParameters()).Single();
//return last insert uid
```